# How to add property to response in JSP?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

Let me start by saying I am new to JSP. I have searched and searched for the answer to my question with no luck. In JSP, I want to add properties to my response for when I call the JSP. For example, if I was to add the 'name' property and gave it the value of 'Bob'. I want to be able to call response.name in the javascript code and have access to 'Bob'. How can I do this? I tried looking at setProperty, but I don't think response qualifies as a JavaBean.

Comment: var jsact="<%=act.name%>"; here act is java object. jsact is js variable. You can call java object in js of jsp. And in JSP response is implicit object dont know whether its possible to assign new parameter to it.

Comment: I think the problem with that is that I don't know how to set the property of act. For example, response doesn't, by default have a name property, so in the Java code, I'm not sure what to write. After all, I couldn't write response.name = 'bob'. I would just get an error saying that name does not exist as a property of response.

Comment: Y dont you set that name parameter to jsact in js itself. Its easier way.